# Android dev: what is the difference between INSTANTIATING a View and DEFINING it in the XML Layout

Tags: android-layout, android-view

I'm a newbie in Android development.

I have Eclipse with ADT (sdk version: 17 , Android 4.2).

I don't understand what is the difference between:

- **DEFINING** a View (via **visual editor** provided by ADT or directly in the **XML layout file** corresponding to the current activity)

and

- **INSTANTIATING** a View (**PASSING THE CONTEXT AS PARAMETER**) such as: **TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());**   (taken from : [What is 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android) , first asnwer)

and

- **INSTANTIATING** a View (**WITHOUT PASSING THE CONTEXT AS PARAMETER**) such as: **TextView tv = new TextView();**

Thank in advance for any advice.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use your terminology:

When DEFINING a `View` in XML (or the ADT editor - which just creates the XML for you), it still needs to be inflated by a layout inflater. A layout inflater will INSTANTIATE the `View`(s) for you. This can be done behind the scenes - such as when you call `Activity.setContentView()`, or directly using `View.inflate()`. The inflater effectively just runs through the XML and instantiates all of the Views it contains.

When INSTANTIATING a `View`, you're giving it the `Context` so it has a reference to resources - so it can load images, strings, dimensions etc - plus other Android related functionality (which you can probably ignore for now).

You can't INSTANTIATE a `View` without the context.

Comment: Thank you. Would you be so kind to explain me also the difference between using setContentView() and inflate()?

Comment: `setContentView()` sets the layout or `View` to put inside your `Activity`. `View.inflate` inflates (i.e. builds) a `View` hierarchy from the XML you provide and returns it, for you to do something else with (unless you pass a `ViewGroup` as a parent - in which case it puts the View hierarchy it builds inside the parent you provide).